# Can I e-mail as WAV file and get back a MP3 file?

Tags: email, conversion, mp3, web, wav

Is there a service where I could e-mail as WAV file and get it back a MP3 file?

Comment: Do you have any objections to just convert the WAV to MP3 yourself? Problem is that WAV files are uncompressed and usually much larger than most email servers will allow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do it yourself - it's much easier with the [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php) encoder.

Comment: This is a much quicker, cheaper (on bandwidth), not to mention secure, way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that you can do this, but you can upload the file to a website like [www.zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com) and select an MP3 to be the returned format.

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling "Up to 100MB" could become an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context, I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/faq?i=lame-mp3&s=install) + LAME encoder can do this for you very quickly, and for free, without having to upload anything.